# Докажите, что количество делителей квадрата натурального числа - число нечетное

Tags: математика, деление, теория-чисел

**Задача:**

> Докажите, что количество делителей квадрата натурального числа - число
> нечетное. Сформулируйте и докажите обратное утверждение.

**Указание:**

> Все делители числа `n^2`, кроме одного, можно разбить на пары вида `(d; n^2 / d)`, где `d != n^2 / d`.

*Кроме одного* - это когда делитель `n`?

---

---

1. Можно ли это доказать более наглядно?
2. И как выглядит обратное утверждение и его доказательство?

Comment: Куда ж еще более наглядно... А обратное - если число делителей числа - четное, то это не квадрат :) Доказательство - от противного. Да, "кроме одного* - это когда d==n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Доказывается элементарно.

Расмотрим 2 варианта: `n = 1` и `n > 1`.

При `n = 1`:

`n**2 = 1`, а значит делитель только один - единица. Утверждение справедливо.

При `n > 1`:

Пусть `n = (p1**a1)(p2**a2)...(pk**ak)` - разложение числа `n` на простые множители. Тогда количество делителей этого числа равно `(a1+1)(a2+1)...(ak+1)`.

Возведём `n` в квадрат и посмотрим разложение на простые множители: `n2 = n**2 = (p1**(2*a1))(p1**(2*a2))...(pk*(2*ak))`.

Число делителей `n2` равно `(2a1 + 1)(2a2 + 1)...(2ak + 1)` - число гарантированно нечётное.

---

**В обратную сторону.**

Если у положительного целого числа нечётное число делителей, то оно является квадратом целого числа.

Пусть число делителей нечётно. Это либо единица, либо больше единицы. Единица равна квадрату единицы - для неё утверждение справедливо.

Пусть теперь у числа `n > 1` нечетное количество делителей. Разложим его на простые множители: `n = (p1**a1)(p2**a2)...(pk**ak)`. Количество делителей этого числа `(a1+1)(a2+1)...(ak+1)` - нечётное. Следовательно, каждое из чисел `(ai+1)` - нечётно. Следовательно каждое число `ai` - чётно, то есть представимо в виде `ai = 2*bi`, где `bi > 0`.

Возьмём число `m = (p1**b1)(p2**b2)...(pk**bk)`. Очевидно, что `m*m == n`.