# Как можно увеличить быстродействие этого кода на C++

Tags: c++

Решал задачу на нахождение чисел с нечетным делителем, столкнулся с проблемой, она заключается в том, что не хватает времени, как можно ускорить этот код?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    int left, right; // отрезок на котором нужно найти эти числа
    std::cin >> left >> right;

    int counter;
    int pos = 1;
    for (int i = left; i <= right; i++) {
        counter = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) counter++;
        }
        if (counter % 2 == 1) {
            std::cout << pos << " " << i << " " << counter << " " << sqrt(i) << '\n';
            pos++;
        }
        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _с нечетным делителем_ - может быть всё-таки **с нечетным числом делителей**?

Answer (score 4):

Зная что число с нечётным количеством делителей - полный квадрат ([док.во](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1262598/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5)) можно составить алгоритм:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    int left, right; // отрезок на котором нужно найти эти числа
    std::cin >> left >> right;

    int l = ceil(sqrt(left));
    int r = floor(sqrt(right));

    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
        std::cout << i * i << " " << i << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это скорее не линейный, а O(sqrt(N)) :)

Comment: К ответу выше хочу добавить, что для возведения в квадрат стоит просто писать i * i

Comment: Производная от i*i будет 2*j+k т.е.  можно через производую ещё ускорить, и обойтись даже без умножения. 1,2,3,4,5 => 0+1, (1+3)=4, (4+5)=9, (9+7)=16,(16+9)=25 при желании автор может реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

В добавок могу посоветовать использовать в начале программы:

```
ios::sync_with_stdio(0); 
cin.tie(0); 
cout.tie(0);
```

Это ускорит работу `cin` и `cout`.